# Object's field value into an aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, aura, javascript-controller

I am not very familiar with aura component.
How I get the value of a field into an aura component (more exactly, inside the controller .js of a component)? (Es: status of case)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you have any example code you can share of what you're trying to do? Your question is just vague enough that it could be interpreted several ways, so some example code would help clarify what your intended use is.

Comment: I need to access the value of the status field of the case object in the controller. I had tried using component.get ('v.status'); but it did not work